# Is it possible to stop Oracle DB grants for specific user?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, sql-grant

My company uses Oracle 12c database. We have several users defined in the database and have a few roles defined as well. My preference is for our development team to grant access to new tables/procedures via roles rather than granting directly to the users.

For instance lets say we have user USER1 and a role READ_ROLE granted to USER1. If a developer creates a new table TABLE1

- They should not be allowed to grant read access on TABLE1 directly to USER1
- Instead they should grant read access to READ_ROLE which indirectly gives the same access to USER1

Unfortunately we have team with 40+ developers and over time folks have been assigning the grants directly to users rather than roles. With 100k+ grants, a few hundred tables, and dozens of users it becomes hard to manage which is why I prefer to use roles. Also a bit hard to manually police it.

Is there a systematic way with oracle DB to stop new grants from being allowed for a user? Maybe something that causes an exception when someone tries to add new grants?

Comment: *"over time folks have been assigning the grants directly to users "* - You allow developers to execute DDL freestyle in Production? If so, rogue grants are probably the least of your concerns.

Comment: You can try with a system trigger 'BEFORE GRANT'

Comment: We dont let them exectute ddl in uat or prod only in dev database. They submit a ticket to migrate to uat and prod which require approvals. I cant catch everything asim not a dba and have too many other tasks to police it on a daily basis in uat. So looking for automated way to stop it in dev/uat before it even gets to prod.

Comment: Documented standards to follow and good peer reviews before migrating out of dev would help.

Comment: There is nothing systematic in place to stop a developer from migrating to UAT. I cant spend every day looking at something trivial like this - I have a hundred other daily things I have to do. We do pier reviews but by the time prod release is on us its too late to change anything. Better to force developers to do the right thing. I am discussing the trigger option with our DBA today.

Comment: Instead of stopping developers from doing the wrong thing you may want to encourage them to do the right thing.  If you can build a standard procedure that grants all the necessary privileges, it could be easier for developers to call that procedure than to write the grant statements.

Comment: I do hear what you are saying and i have sent plenty of emails with best practices. 40+ developers in 4 countries. 75% in india so 10 hour time difference. I can only send so many emails that noone reads till i have to put something systematic in place to force people to do the right rhing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by APC you should not permit developers to grant anything directly on production database. This might be OK when you have a small application with 3-4 developers only. In your scale this is really dangerous and you as a vendor cannot ensure any quality/security on your application.

Anyway, you can use a system trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER grant_trigger
  BEFORE GRANT ON {your_schema}.SCHEMA

DECLARE

  user_list ora_name_list_t;
  number_of_grantees PLS_INTEGER;
  res INTEGER

BEGIN
  IF (ora_sysevent = 'GRANT') THEN
    number_of_grantees := ora_grantee(user_list);
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO res
    FROM DBA_USERS
    WHERE USERNAME MEMBER OF user_list;

    IF res > 0 THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'It is not permitted to GRANT directly to USER. Use ROLE instead');
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

You may add additional conditions, e.g.

```
DECLARE

  user_list ora_name_list_t;
  number_of_grantees PLS_INTEGER;
  res INTEGER

  privilege_list ora_name_list_t;
  number_of_privileges PLS_INTEGER;

BEGIN
  IF (ora_sysevent = 'GRANT') THEN
    number_of_grantees := ora_grantee(user_list);
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO res
    FROM DBA_USERS
    WHERE USERNAME MEMBER OF user_list;

    IF res > 0 THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'It is not permitted to GRANT directly to USER. Use ROLE instead');
    END IF;
  END IF;

    number_of_privileges := ora_privilege_list(privilege_list);
    IF 'DELETE' MEMBER OF privilege_list THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'You must not grant "DELETE"');
       -- Other privileges as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE would be permitted.
    END IF;

    IF (ora_dict_obj_type = 'TABLE') THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010, 'You must not grant anything to a TABLE');
       -- Other objects like VIEW or PROCEDURE would be permitted.
    END IF;

END;
```

See [SYSTEM TRIGGER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS99887) for more details. Ensure your developers do not have `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` or `CREATE ANY TRIGGER` privilege, otherwise they can just disable the trigger and thus bypass it.

Comment: I was looking for something exactly like this. Im no dba but will discuss this option with our dba. Btw please see my response to apc. We dont allow developers to run ddl in prod or even uat. They submit ticket and the enterprise db team reviews the script and stages in uat or prod. Unfortunately that ent db team gets requests from a hundred other teams each of which has different set of best practices. So they wont police grants they just make sure the script doesnt violate a specific set of conditions. Will try your suggestion in dev and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Perfect solution! Tested it today and works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: We ended up doing the grant at the database level rather than at the schema level (before grant on database) as this solution only requires one trigger rather than one per schema. But still good solution.